# Unable to cast base class to derived class

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism

I have base class as Animal and child class as Dog

Here is the code:

```
class Animal
{
    public int Legs { get; set; }

    public string Name  { get; set; }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public int noOfTail { get; set; }
}
```

In My Main Method when I execute below I get the exception:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d = (Dog)a;
    }
```

but when I first cast my derived class to parent I don't get any exception, and that is why I am confused, can somebody explain reason behind it.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Dog d = new Dog();
        a = d;
        d = (Dog)a;
    }
```

Comment: In first example you are doing  down-casting (specialization, explicit typecasting) that is not allowed in your case, whereas in the second example you are doing upcasting (generalization, implicit typecasting). Details: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generalization-and-specialization-in-java/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Case two you have an instance of *dog* and *animal*

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Dog d = new Dog();
```

Then you have `reference copy` of *dog* to *animal*

```
a = d;
```

So the *a* is points to *d* and *d* is a *dog* instance and instance properties like **noOfTail** is still exist but is hidden and not available in object a.
and then you have this line :

```
d = (Dog)a;
```

In last line you have reference copy of *d* to *a* ,so *d* is point to where *a* is point to so everything is okay.

but in case one you want copy one `Instance of child class` *Dog* to an instance of *Animal* so the properties of child class will be lost. you need to confirm that with Compiler and say to him you know instance properties like `noOfTail`  will not be available any more 
your code most be like this :

```
 Animal a = new Animal();
 Dog d = new Dog();
 d = (a as Dog);
```

Answer (score 7):

`Animal` object cannot be cast to a `Dog` type. A `Dog` object, on the other hand, can be cast to `Dog` type even if you store a `Dog` object in a variable of `Animal` type.

In your first example you attempt to cast an `Animal` to `Dog`, which fails, because object is of a wrong class. In your second example you assign `a = d`, so now variable `a` has type `Animal`, but its runtime type is `Dog`. That is why the second cast works.

**Note:** This is only the technical part of your problem, but there is also a logical component to it: your class hierarchy lets you instantiate `Animal` class, which is not a leaf class.

A better approach would be to make `Animal` an interface or an abstract class. This way you would be able to instantiate only the "actual" animals (`Dog` and whatever else you wish to derive from `Animal`), while it would not be possible to create an instance of `Animal` without saying what kind of animal it represents.

Answer (score 2):

Animal is not a Dog. Dog is an Animal. This is why you cannot cast an Animal to a Dog in the first example.

In the second example it works because Animal has been assigned the value of Dog. When you assigned `a = d` the Animal became a Dog.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast a base class to a derived class, but you can do the opposite: cast a derived class to a base class.

Your second attempt works for a very simple reason: `a = d`; => you are assigning a derived class instance to a base class instance.
 that [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) fundamental is called [polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Dog d = new Dog();
        a = d; // you can do that but you cant do d=a
        d = (Dog)a;
    }
```

To understand it better try to delve into that piece of code:

```
public void polymorphism()
{
    // thats wrong and the compiler will throw an exception (at design time) because animal is not a dog
    Dog d = new Animal();
    // thats correct becasue dog is an animal
    Animal a = new Dog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Dog d = new Dog();
d = (Dog)a;
```

So to summary up wrt to **Animal** and **Dog** class,  we can state that an object to become an animal it must possess legs and name property and an object to become dog it must have nooftails property in addition to name and legs property.

Lets simplify by giving each object's properties explicit values.

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.Name="Monkey";
a.Legs=2;
Dog d = new Dog();
a.Name="Dog";
a.Legs=4;
a.noOfTail=1;
```

Assume below statement doesn't throw any compiler error.

```
 d = (Dog)a;
```

What does it mean? Legs and name which is a monkey object you are trying to make or transform or cast the monkey object as a dog without noOftails property, it's **nooftails** property which uniquely identifies or differentiates  the Base Animal from derived Dog class which defeats the basic purpose of Inheritance.

Hence compiler prevents you from making such absurd cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert, simple approach is to just serialize and deserialize it using json.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChildClass>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseObject))
```